# Using a chrome cast can I stream directly from my iPhone?

Tags: ios, google-cast

I would like to send screen captures to my iphone to the chromecast or video from the camera. Is this possible or does ChromeCast SDK only stream from the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an app that sends images and video from your phone, you just need to create a mini-server on the phone to serve them from.  Then just tell your receiver (probably the Styled one), to access the local server (on your iPhone).