# Does Google Cast support screencasting from Android devices?

Tags: android, tablet, google-cast

Does Google Cast support screencasting from Android devices?  For example, could we implement it into our tablet app to broadcast our screen to a receiver device running on a bigscreen TV, for demonstrations and events?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21612011/246901) post mentions creating a mini-server on an iPhone to serve content from.  Would it be possible to create a mini-server within our Android app that captures and broadcasts the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cast doesn't support screen casting.  However, you could certainly create a tiny web-server (such as http://tjws.sourceforge.net/) which serves images you've created. (Remember to shut it down when the user turns off the screen -- to save power) You should even be able to use the [Styled Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver) for that.

Answer (score 1):

No, Google Cast only supports streaming to a Chromecast, from any Chromecast supported device. 
Also the "app" must be chromecast capable, so you would have to do what the post suggests, create your own app that acts as the middle-man in-between your device and your chromecast-supported-TV.

**Simple Alternative For Screen Sharing**:

On the other hand, a faster solution (if all you need is share your screen) is to use [Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/) and mirror your computer's display to the bigger screen or use join.me so users seeing your screen can also see your Android device.